How can I deploy SvelteKit IO app with two ports?
I'm using the SvelteKit IO library for sockets in my SvelteKit application.
My main application, when built, runs on port 4173. My socket runs on 3001.
Here's the SKIO setup code: I can't change 3001 to 4173 without encountering an error.
skio.setup('http://localhost:3001', {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:4173",
        credentials: true,
    },
}).then(io => {
    if (browser)
        return;
    io.on('connect', socket => {
        socket.on('message', (message) => {
            if (message.game_stop === true) {
                socket.disconnect()
            } else {
                socket.emit('message', message);
                socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
            }
        });
    });
});

How do I deploy such an app with two ports?

Let's sum up the requirements of your application:

needs to expose multiple ports (since socket.io can fallback to http and we want to use http otherwise as well)
needs to support websockets and thus long-running processes

It seems unlikely that you will find a high-level service provider which allows that, neither netlify nor vercel do (at least at this point).

Lower-level service providers will allow you to do almost anything you want, however this comes at the cost of requiring more expertise and increased complexity.
Since the paths you could take here are almost limitless I will only give an overview of some of the ways you could approach this. For specifics please comment, open a new question, or look for other questions or documentation online.
Approaches with lower-level service providers
You could:

Package the application as a docker (or oci) container.
Package the application as a virtual machine image e.g. built via packer

In both cases you then have a range of options for deployment that many cloud providers such as aws, google cloud or microsoft azure will offer.
For docker:

Deploy on a virtual machine. E.g. see deploying containers on google compute engine
Deploy on a services that manages scaling for you, such as AWS Fargate or App Runner.
Deploy it on a kubernetes cluster

For virtual machine images:

Deploy as a virtual machine. E.g. AWS EC2
Deploy on a service that manages scaling for you, such as AWS EC2 Autoscaling

(Similar options exist when deploying as webassembly, however, due to the immaturity of that ecosystem I have omitted the option above)
